# Do we have a Java correspondent to .NET "mustinherit" or "notinheritable"?

Tags: java, oop

How can We state that a certain class in Java must be inherited and not directly instantiated  from itself, or the opposite, how to force it not being inherited? In .NET we are able to use the "mustinherit" and "notinheritable" modifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> must be inherited and not directly instantiated from itself

Make it `abstract`.

> or the opposite, how to force it not being inherited?

Make it `final`.

Answer (score 6):

A java class that you can't instantiate is abstract

```
abstract class A {
```

A java class that you can't inherit is final

```
final class A {
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with .NET, so I can base my answer on my understanding of names. 
"mustinherit" means `abstract` in java
"noninheritable" means `final` in java